# An Alternative for Firebase functions ? Is it okay to run them on a VM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, virtual-machine, google-cloud-functions, cold-start

I am using firebase functions for an Uberlike product. I can't get expected performance. Specially it takes a long time to load data from realtime-db. Up to 2-3 seconds for a read.
It's may be due to called start, which is discussed here. => [Why is Cloud Functions for Firebase taking 25 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637519/why-is-cloud-functions-for-firebase-taking-25-seconds)

So I decided to move the functionality of these functions to a VM instance. Using firebase `onWrite` and admin SDK, a similar functionality can be achieved on a virtual machine.

Is it okay to do so? Will I get any scalability issue?

Comment: have you considered using parse server?

Comment: @Mox nope. We are using firebase realtime db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible to run similar code on your own hardware/VM. In fact that is how many of Firebase's own back-end processes ran, before Cloud Functions was available.

What you'll miss is the auto-scaling of Cloud Functions though. Your machine/VM will always be running, and has a limited capacity (how much it can handle). Unlike Firebase, it has a fixed capacity.

Cloud Functions on the other hand, scaled down to 0 when there are no request, and scales up to meet demand as needed. Whether that is needed for your use-case, only you can determine.

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much Frank. I'll do so.